# How to add dynamic layout in ViewGroup in android?

Tags: android, viewgroup, pinchzoom

I created FrameLayout dynamically in my activity. Like this

```
  FrameLayout path_zoom;
  path_zoom = new FrameLayout(this);
  path_zoom.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(1500,1119));
```

Now i want to add this dynamic layout in ViewGroup for layout zooming. I need to add my layout like this.

```
   View v = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.ground_zoom, null, false);
```

Instead of null i want to pass ViewGroup object. How can i do this? Can any body tell me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make a object for ViewGroup..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup)SelectorView.your_context.getParent();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ground_zoom , parentView);
```